# sql command for reading a particular sheet, column 

Tags: sql, excel, r, sqlcommand, import-from-excel

This is probably a very stupid question for SQL stalwarts, but I just want one SQL command.

Details,

I am using a data analysis tool called R, this tool uses ODBC to read data from XLS. I am now trying to read data from an XLS file. The ODBC tool in R accepts SQL commands.

Question,

Can someone give me an SQL command that will read data from an XLS file's
- Specified sheet
- Specified column [by name]
- Specified row [Specified just by Row Index]

Thanks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have set the connection to the file, you can use following statement:

```
select [columnname] from [sheetname$] where [columnname] = 'somevalue'
```

Not sure about the row index thing. But you can make use of where clause if each row in the file has serial number or any such unique value.

Answer (score 5):

With the query below you can read the data from row 61 of cloumn A, & G is supposed to read all columns till G.

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$a61:G]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample query:

```
SELECT [sheet1$.col1], [sheet1$.col2], [sheet2$.col1] 
FROM   [sheet1$], [sheet2$] 
WHERE  [sheet1$.col1] = [sheet2$.col2]
```

This assumes an excel document with 2 sheets (`sheet1` and `sheet2`).  Each sheet has 2 columns, with the first row as headers (`col1` and `col2` in each sheet).

Here's the complete code:

```
> library(RODBC)
> conn <- odbcConnectExcel('c:/tmp/foo.xls')
> query <- "select [sheet1$.col1], [sheet1$.col2], [sheet2$.col1] 
            from [sheet1$], [sheet2$] 
            where [sheet1$.col1] = [sheet2$.col2];"
> result <- sqlQuery(conn, query)
> odbcClose(conn)
> result
  col1 col2 col1.1
1    1    3      5
2    2    4      6
3    3    5      7
```

I've never found a way to deal with row numbers.  I just create an extra column and fill down sequentially.  Not sure if that works for you.